# jquery 1.8.3 and Yii: (window).height() = (document).height()

Tags: jquery, yii

My project works on Yii 1.1.12 (and included jQuery 1.7.2). Now I'm try to update to Yii 1.1.13 (and included jQuery 1.8.3). Suddenly discover than `$(window).height()` now return the **document** height, not window.

I'm try Yii 1.1.12 and jQuery 1.8.3 - the same result: `$(window).height() = $(document).height()`. But $(window).height() less, indeed.

Return to Yii 1.1.12 and jQuery 1.7.2 - and have good result. 
jQuery 1.8.3 without Yii works properly.

What does it mean? In which direction I must research for solving this problem?

**Solution.**
It turns out, I have some files with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). So, they corrupted `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration (on local Windows machine), and jQuery can't works properly with this document. Now I clean BOM from files and jQuery works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens when your page is rendered in quirks mode. Reference: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12388

Try changing your doctype to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

You said that jQuery 1.8.3 without Yii works properly. That might be because you are using a different doctype for your non-Yii page.

Comment: Thank you very much! You give me right direction. Now I have solution and update already.