# making a div fill the entire screen with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In jquery it's easy enough. Just do the following:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
<div id="test" style="background: black"></div>
</body>

<script>
$('#test').width($(window).width());
$('#test').height("100%");
</script>
```

Demo:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/scripts/demo/fullsize-jquery.html

In D3, however, it's not quite as clear to me. Here's what I'm doing:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
<div id="test" style="background: black"></div>
</body>

<script>
d3.select("#test").attr("width", window.innerWidth);
d3.select("#test").attr("height", "100%");
</script>
```

Demo:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/scripts/demo/fullsize-d3.html

It's like the div isn't being resized at all.

So how do I do, with D3, what I'm doing with jquery? Thanks!

Comment: Am I supposed to see a black screen? Neither scripts work for me with firefox 19

Comment: Hmmm - interesting. I'm using Chrome. Let me figure out what's up.

Comment: Well the jquery one is working in Firefox now. I replaced $(window).height() with "100%"

Comment: Oh I googled a bit and got [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425237/jquery-1-8-3-and-yii-window-height-document-height), that seems to be the proper solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jquery is setting the css height. You can achieve the same thing in d3 by:

```
d3.select("#test").style("height", "100%");
```

Comment: Hm, beat me by a few secs. The error in the original code is that he used attr() that sets the html attribute instead of CSS. Also, window.innerHeight seems to work fine here too.

Comment: What about for making the height 100% for the force layout object?: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-size

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use css to do this.
in the css file:

```
#fullScreen{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

and in the html file:

```
<body>
    <div id="fullScreen"></div>
</body>
```