# why are the horizontal bars appearing?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In [making a div fill the entire screen with d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859896/making-a-div-fill-the-entire-screen-with-d3) I figured out how to make the horizontal scroll bars go away but the same technique isn't working for this:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/d3test.php

Any ideas as to why?

That's basically an adaptation of http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because SVG is, by default, an inline element.

See previouis answer here: [Why is there a vertical scrollbar on my svg at 100%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758638/why-is-there-a-vertical-scrollbar-on-my-svg-at-100)

set

```
svg{display: block;}
```